# Pandas unhashable type:list while I'm using a string

Tags: python, pandas

```
items = ['1', '2', '3']
for item in items:
   df_list[item]= df.loc[file_df['Item'] == item]
```

This works fine. However if my item list is something else, for example:

```
items = [{'code': '1', 'other_needed_value': 1}, {'code': '2', 'other_needed_value': 2}, {'code': '3', 'other_needed_value': 3}]
for item in items:
    code = item['code']
    df_list[item]= df.loc[file_df['Item'] == code]
```

Obviously I'm comparing file_df['Item'] to a string, however I get this error from pandas

```
unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How should I solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your list of dictionaries called `item` or is this a typo? Also it'd be good to put the full Traceback error so we can see which line is causing the problem

Comment: Sorry it's a typo while changing the variable names. Will edit

Comment: The problem isn't the comparison. The problem is trying to use `item` as a dict key, when `item` is itself a `dict`. If you meant to use `code` as the dict key, then that's just a typo. Otherwise please refer to the linked duplicate.

Comment: In the future, you should also try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your code first before asking. This starts by trying to understand the error message; in particular, what part of that line of code causes the error. You may find it helpful to break that line up into smaller parts. In this case, for example, you might have assigned `df.loc[file_df['Item'] == code]` to a temporary variable first, before assigning that to `df_list[item]`. You would have immediately seen that the problem was in the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df_list[item]` should be `df_list[code]`. What's happening here is that the list `df_list` is being indexed with `item` which, in the 2nd code example above, is actually a dictionary, hence the error. What OP wants is to take the 'code' value of the dictionary. The desired code can also be written as:

```
for item in items:
    df_list[item['code']]= df.loc[file_df['Item'] == item['code']]
```

Comment: No worries. In the future, if you encounter this type of error and aren't sure which variable is causing the problem, you can always try debugging by setting a breakpoint in the code where the error is being thrown and then examining which variable is a dictionary. [Here's a tutorial on how to do that in VSCode](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-debug-python-scripts-in-visual-studio-code/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to run your code,
but i see that you use

```
for item in items:
    code = item['code']
```

what is the type of item
it seems it is a dictionary
because in the next line you use
item['code'] ==> hence a dictionary
maybe you were trying to assign df_list[code]?

little more code/output would help